# Sudden 404 not found error on all files in my Java GAE app without any changes to files or configurations

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

I'm running a paid GAE app written in Java and it's id is clip-share, so the url is http://clip-share.appspot.com/.

I've run it for more than 10 months, and since 2 days ago, it starts not working with 404 not found error on all static and dynamic URL.

When I connect to my app's URL, it just throws this message that there is no index.html file which really does exist.

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.
```

I tried re-deploy this app for a few times, but it works with no problem just only for a few minutes right after the deploy, but doesn't work after that.

And also searched for the 404 not found problem, I found this thread but there is no specific information about the cause and some way to solve it.

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/8liP4T-wbSo/discussion

So, what's happening? and how can I handle it?

**EDIT:**

I found a workaround for this problem, that is making another version, say version 2, and set it as default. But you can still see the problem in this URL for version 1, just put `1.` just before the URL. (I want to show you the full URL to the version 1, but I'm rather new to stackoverflow.com, and not permitted to post more than 2 URLs in one question.)

So, the same code and configuration in two different versions, but only version 2, the newer one works.

Comment: did you over run the limits of data usage and disk space

Comment: It's not such a famous app and is still far from the limits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be that there was a configuration problem in Google App Engine plugin of Eclipse. That I have several GAE projects in one Eclipse workspace, and other GAE project accidentally deployed to the clip-share. So it looks like that there was 404 not found problems happening, suddenly. Anyway, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

in web.xml should be welcome file tag. Perhaps you have there /index.html. Find in web.xml "/index.html" and change it to "index.html".

index.html file should be in war folder: /war/index.html

Comment: As I wrote above, it works for a few minutes just after the deployment, and start to fail with 404. Quite strange, isn't it?